# Use google drive to backup and synchronize appdata?

Tags: google-drive-api

Can gDrive be used to backup application-specific data files, i.e. game save states that are not traditionally user facing? Would this allow cross-device migration?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is possible.  Drive apps can create files with arbitrary MIME types.  Synchronization is therefore available by downloading the file(s) from multiple places/devices.